# How to make changes to Sqlite database with EF Core?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite

I am able to follow this example from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) completely fine. I'm using UWP by the way.

Now, I am trying to make changes, say, by adding some `NewColumn` property to the `Blog` class. Ran another `Add-Migration` command, and I get the **"No such column"** error on `NewColumn`.

What should I do to make the update? I understand that `Update-Database` doesn't work on UWP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add columns to a sqlite database via migrations due to limitations in the sqlite engine - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations

Comment: Can you suggest other alternatives? I'm just trying to make a UWP app with any kind of database integration...

Comment: Maybe use sqlite-net.PCL instead?

Comment: EF Core propably changed, but "AddColumn" is marked as "Supported" now. Still have the same error message though

Comment: @jpelletier you need s custom build of sqlite

Comment: @ErikEJ No, it's working! add-migration was failing because I had some codes accessing the databases in startup.cs and I have to comment this code when I execute add-migration. After everything work #1